# How to round off values in a combined dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, rounding

I have a combined dictionary called **frequencies** which compares the frequency of the same word in two different sets of texts:

```
{'banana': [0, 0.0001505742903433696], 'pear': [0, 2.1510612906195657e-05], 'pineapple': [0, 2.1510612906195657e-05], 'orange': [0, 4.3021225812391315e-05], 'apple': [0, 2.1510612906195657e-05]...}
```

I want to round and reduce decimals so it looks like this, for instance: `{'pear': [0, 2,15]}`

I have tried this code:

```
for x in frequencies:
for key, value in frequencies.items():
        frequencies[key]=round(float(value), 2)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
     frequencies[key]=round(float(value), 2)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: Also 2.1510612906195657e-05 is not 2.15

Comment: you should do it like this: frequencies[key]=round(float(value[0]), 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen because your `values` is a `list`. you need iterate over values then round them:

```
for key, value in frequencies.items():
    frequencies[key] = [round(v,2) for v in value]
```